# python argparse module AttributeError

Tags: python, argparse

I'm learning the `argparse` module, and I wrote code as follows:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
               help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
               const=sum, default=max,
               help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print args.accumulate(args.integers)
```

I saved it as `argparse.py`, but when I run it in `cmd`, it shows:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ArgumentParser'

what's the problem? Thank you for your help.

Comment: rename your argparse.py file as you are importing from that, you also need to delete any agparse.pyc file

Comment: When you `import` you are loading yourself, rather than the standard library module.

Comment: @evbo:  if its any consolation, you are not the first person to have had this issue, and you won't be the last.  This issue comes up here at least once a week.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you say `import` in Python, the interpreter runs a search to find a file with that name. It first looks for the file in the current folder and then in other paths, such as, /usr/lib/python.

Therefore, when you're saying `import argparse` and naming your script `argparse.py`, Python takes your file and import it as is.

To avoid this, change the name of your file to something else than argparse.py.

Comment: Happy that I got this in first google search :) 

Thank you !

Comment: So if someone read this in 2023, be patient =).
My stupid case is:

i had two files in same folder:
work/create_parser.py
work/argparse.py

i tried to call:
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() 
in file create_parser.py

so python3 still throw error:
AttributeError: module 'argparse' has no attribute 'ArgumentParser'

until i delete\mv file argparse.py =)
So that's why imports works in same lvl first